# C programming language :if statements are not working correctly with characters

Tags: c, if-statement, chars

I'm trying to make this program say good but it says okay instead
though I made the variable value the same of the if test value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char history[200];
    history == "NY school";

    if(history == "NY school")
    {
        printf("good");
    }
    else{printf("okay");}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `strcpy` and `strcmp` to assign and compare strings

Comment: You are comparing pointers, hence the error. Also `man 3 strcmp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
        //^^^^^^^^ Don't forget to include this library for the 2 functions

int main() {  

    char history[200];
    strcpy(history, "NY school");
  //^^^^^^^Copies the string into the variable
    if(strcmp(history, "NY school") == 0) {
     //^^^^^^ Checks that they aren't different
        printf("good");
    } else {
        printf("okay");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

For more information about `strcpy()` see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

For more information about `strcmp()` see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: Just doing `char history[200] = "NY school";` works also.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the function `strcmp`

i.e.

```
  if (strcmp(history ,"NY school") == 0) ....
```

Otherwise you are comparing pointers

Plus change

```
  history == "NY school";
```

to use `strcpy`

Answer (score 1):

Strings cannot be assigned (which would use a single `=`, not `==` as in your code).   Look up the `strcpy()` function in the standard header `<string.h>`.

Also, strings (or any arrays, for that matter) cannot be compared using the relational operators (`==`, `!=`, etc) - such comparisons compare pointers (the address of the first element of the array) not the contents of the strings.   To compare strings, use the `strcmp()` function, again in `<string.h>`.

Answer (score -1):

With a bit of implementation defined optimiser luck this might work also:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char * history = "NY school";

  if (history == "NY school") /* line 7 */
  {
    printf("good");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("okay");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

At least it works when being compiled by `gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2`, with no optimisation btw.

The code shown above prints:

```
good
```

During compilation it however triggers the warning (for line 7):

```
 warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
```

Comment: As other comments and replies have pointed out, strings cannot be compared using the == operator.   It is necessary to use the strcmp() function (which is declared in standard header <string.h>).

Comment: @Rob: The code I show does not compare "strings", but pointers to them.

Comment: That's right.     The problem is that there is no guarantee whether those pointers are equal or unequal.